# Suficient condition for tensor product of vector spaces..

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

Can anyone help me showing the following:

Let $E$, $F$, $G$ and $H$ vector spaces and $\varphi:E\times F\rightarrow G$ a bilinear map. If for every $\psi:E\times F\rightarrow H$ bilinear there is an unique linear map $f:G\rightarrow H$ such that $\psi=f\circ \varphi$ then $(G, \varphi)$ is a tensor product of $E$ and $F$.

The definition I have for tensor product of vector spaces is:

**Definition:** Let $E, F$ and $G$ be vector spaces and $\varphi:E\times F\rightarrow G$ a bilinear map. We say the pair $(G, \varphi)$ is a tensor product of $E$ and $F$ if:

**(i)** $\textrm{im}(\varphi)=G$.

**(ii)** For every $\psi:E\times F\rightarrow H$ bilinear, where $H$ is an arbitrary vector space, there is linear map $f:G\rightarrow H$ such that $\psi=f\circ \varphi$.

So using this definition it suffices showing the map $\varphi:E\times F\rightarrow G$ is surjective for solving my problem...

Any help will be welcome..Thanks

Comment: Is the above true for **any** vector space $\,H\,$ ?

Comment: Which definition of the tensor product do you use?

Comment: I was writing exactly that @BorisNovikov =D

Comment: That's right @DonAntonio

Answer (score 2):

(i) is not correct, it should be $\langle \mathrm{im}(\phi) \rangle = G$.

In order to solve the "exercise" (which in fact, is the equivalence between your wrong definition (which should be seen as a characterization) and the correct definition), you only have to show (i). To do that, apply the given universal property to see that the inclusion $\langle \mathrm{im}(\phi) \rangle \hookrightarrow G$ induces a bijection $\hom(G,H) \to \hom(\langle \mathrm{im}(\phi) \rangle,H)$ for every $H$. This implies that $\langle \mathrm{im}(\phi) \rangle \to G$ is an isomorphism (Yoneda Lemma; any argument (especially the ones which will appear in the other answers) are repetitions of the proof of the Yoneda Lemma).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. As to $(i)$ note that $\textrm{span}\{\varphi(x, y):x\in E, y\in F\}=G$ if and only if $\textrm{im}(\varphi)=G$...

Comment: @PtF: I don't understand your comment. Your claim is false.

Comment: Well: If $g\in G$ then $g\in \textrm{span}\{\varphi(x, y):x\in E, y\in F\}$, that is, $\displaystyle g=\sum_{\alpha\in I}\alpha \varphi(x, y)$ for some scalars $\alpha$. Since $\varphi(x, y)\in \textrm{im}(\varphi)$ and $\textrm{im}(\varphi)$ is closed for vector operations we have $g\in \textrm{im}(\varphi)$ hence $G\subset \textrm{im}(\varphi)$ and the equality $\textrm{im}(\varphi)=G$ holds.

Comment: Conversely if $g\in \textrm{span}\{\varphi(x, y):x\in E, y\in F\}$ then $\displaystyle g=\sum_{\alpha\in I}\alpha_I\varphi(x, y)$ and $g\in \textrm{im}(\varphi)=G$, that is, $\textrm{span}\{\varphi(x, y):x\in E, y\in F\}\subset G$. Now if $g\in G=\textrm{im}(\varphi)$ then $g=\varphi(x, y)$ for some $x\in E$ and $y\in F$ hence $g\in \textrm{span}\{\varphi(x, y):x\in E, y\in F\}$. Therefore, $\textrm{span}\{\varphi(x, y):x\in E, y\in F\}=G$.

Comment: $\phi$ is not linear, it is bilinear. It's image is *not* a subspace (unless $\dim(E),\dim(F) \leq 1$).

Comment: I had forgotten the image of a bilinear map might not be a subspace =( Thanks.. My afirmation was based on Greub's book about multilinear algebra in which he states the fact I afirmed, now I'm confused.. Also there is a proof of my problem in that book but his arguments weren't clear enough for me..

Comment: what would be a good reference for tensor products apart Greub's book?

Comment: Bourbaki's Algèbre, Keith Conrad's notes (available online), etc. I don't think that Greub's makes the claim that the image of a bilinear map is a subspace ...

Comment: I'll take a look at Bourbaki's..Not about the subspace (what I agree it's not true) but he defines the tensor product with the condition $\textrm{span}(\varphi)=G$ and says or equivalently $\textrm{im}(\varphi)=G$...Thanks anyway

Comment: see also [Range of a bilinear map spans codomain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363529/range-of-a-bilinear-mapping-spans-codomain)

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion stems from a lack of understanding of the unconventional notation used by your book (Greub's Multilinear Algebra, 2nd ed).

In p. 2, the book states: "We shall denote $\text{Im}\,\varphi$ the subspace of $G$ *generated* by $S$", where $S$ is the usual image of $\varphi$ and $G$ is the codomain of $\varphi$.

The author does indeed formulate the way you've mentioned. However, *the first thing in the book* (p. 1) is to show that the image of a bilinear map is not in general a subspace. The definition you cite is in p. 4; so just read the previous pages, which are worthwhile.